# How to pass config file to docker run command on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm deploying this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM zenika/alpine-chrome:with-node

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD 1
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=chrome package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile
COPY --chown=chrome src ./src
COPY --chown=chrome tsconfig.json ./
COPY --chown=chrome chrome.json /
RUN yarn run build
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]
CMD ["node", "./dist/start.js"]
```

using this bash script:

```
echo "start deploying"

PROJECT_ID=...
APP_ID=...
LAST_COMMIT_HASH=`git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1`
GCR_ADDRESS="gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$APP_ID:$LAST_COMMIT_HASH"

echo "authenticate with service account"
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./google-key.json
gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-a
gcloud auth configure-docker

echo "build docker image"
docker build . -t $GCR_ADDRESS
echo "push docker image to $GCR_ADDRESS"
docker push $GCR_ADDRESS

echo "create VM, if it doesn't exist yet"
gcloud compute instances create-with-container my-vm --container-image=$GCR_ADDRESS --container-arg="-it --rm --security-opt seccomp=/chrome.json" || {
    echo "failed to create VM. Probably it already exists. Updating existing VM..."
    gcloud compute instances update-container my-vm --container-image=$GCR_ADDRESS --container-arg="-it --rm --security-opt seccomp=/chrome.json"
}
```

When this container is being started by GCE, it throws the error:

```
[FATAL tini (6)] exec -it --rm --security-opt seccomp=/chrome.json failed: No such file or directory
```

How do I pass `seccomp` file to GCE?

Comment: As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container) no such arguments like 'seccomp' listed there.

Answer (score 0):

In your args  `seccomp=/chrome.json`
Seccomp json file is referenced to the root directory.
Verify that the file is really at / (not recommended), If not,  change the path `--security-opt seccomp=/path/to/seccomp/profile.json` [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) to for example `./chrome.json`

Also take in consideration that each argument to append to a container entrypoint  must have a separate flag. Arguments are appended in the order of flags.

Assuming the default entry point of the container (or an entry point overridden with --container-command flag) is a Bourne shell-compatible executable, in order to execute 'ls -l' command in the container:[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container#--container-arg)

```
--container-arg="-c" --container-arg="ls -l"
```